# Check if growth rate is worse than quadratic?

Tags: python, r, algorithms, regression

Let's say I have collected a dataset for estimating algorithmic complexity:

| x | t |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 3 | 9 |
| 4 | 16 |

where x is the input size and t is the elapsed time. This may be `O(1), O(logn), O(n), O(n^2), O(n^3)` etc.. To find the closest class, it would be necessary to run a linear/non-linear regression to fit the data and find the curve of the best fit. However, that would be too time consuming.

My question is: is there a quick way to tell if the rate of growth is worse than O(n^2)?

Comment: why would you need to fit every curve possible? / too many curves? why can't you just fit one curve and see what order polynomial it is?

Comment: You can perform linear regression `log(x)` against `log(t)`. If it is `log(x) = a + b log(t)`, then `x = O(t^b)`. If `b` is statistically greater than 2, then your assumption about complexity worse than `O(x^2)` holds.

Comment: @Nin17 I just need to know if it's worse than polynomial. Fitting one curve is risky because for example quadratic curve with big coefficients can approximate a linear growth rate quiet well.

Comment: @SUTerliakov that's a good idea. Thanks! I will try it out.

Comment: @Nin17 I think this won't work because of lower order coefficients